# How to get rails controller variable in js file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, instance-variables

I have a variable in rails controller like

```
def index
@approveflag = true
end
```

I need to access this variable in my javascript code, I used the code given below
in index.html.erb

```
<script>
alert("<%=@approveflag%>")
<script>
```

It works fine with result "true".But when I moved this code to its corresponding .js file it gives an alert with result string ""<%=@approveflag%>"".
What is the reason. How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

I personally don't like mixing js with erb so I would do something like this:

in index.html.erb

```
<%= content_tag :div, '', id: 'mycontainer', data: { source: @approveflag } %>
```

in js

```
$('#mycontainer').data('source')
alert($('#mycontainer').data('source'))
```

And you have the value from that instance variable, you can add a data attribute in a link_to if you want.

Comment: As far as I tried it out it should be like this:
<%= content_tag :div, '', id: 'mycontainer', data: { source: @approveflag } %>

Comment: Without jQuery: `document.getElementById('mycontainer').dataset.source`

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use the `js` files for this, they are part of the asset pipeline, they are compiled/compressed, and preferably only downloaded once by your client (browser). So they should not change. So at the time the js-files are precompiled, the instance variable is not set and would not make any sense anyway.

But there are a few options.

You can declare a javascript variable in your view, which your javascript can use (for global data)

Code (I use haml):

```
:javascript
  var approveFlag = #{@approveflag} ;
```

You can declare data-tags on elements, if the data belongs to a specific element. But for instance, you could also a `data`-tag on `body` element

For instance

```
%body{:'data-approveflag' => @approveflag}
```

Or something like

```
= link_to 'Collapse', '#', 'data-collapse-div' => 'class-to-collapse'
```

Alternatively you can use ajax/json to download the data. This is clean, but adds an extra delay, so only do this is if the data is not required immediately.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend that you to use the 'gon' gem

**I'm usually more oriented to straight options that don't imply installing, but trust me using 'gon' is very direct and clean**

In your Gemfile add this lines

```
# To use controller variables as javascript variables
gem 'gon'
```

Do a **bundle install** to get/install the gem

In your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb add the following line

```
<%= include_gon %>
```

Then in your controller pass your variable to gon as simple as this

```
gon.your_variable = @controller_variable
```

And in your javascripts retrieve your variable (in this case to show an alert)

```
alert (gon.your_variable) ;
```

And That's it !

For more examples and details see the Wiki page - **https://github.com/gazay/gon/wiki**

Comment: Thanks! 'gon' is great!

Answer (score 1):

In my project I need sometimes user language related translations. So what I did is, I created a simple js file to store the localized text:

```
var TRANSLATION_ARRAY = []

function store_translation(key, value) {
  TRANSLATION_ARRAY[key] = value
}

function get_translation(key) {
  return TRANSLATION_ARRAY[key]
}
```

In den index.html.erb or other components I do this to store the localized text:

```
store_translation('text_id', "<%= translate_with_user_language('text_id') %>")
```

In my plain js file located in app/assets/javascripts i get the localized text by:

```
get_translation('text_id')
```

Works very well. You can use this approach also for other purposes not only translations.