# Rails passing variable from View to Javascript file via HTML data tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my Tweets Controller, I have an array of tweets `@tweets_array`.

In my Tweets View/Show, I passed the value of `@tweets_array` to a data tag so that I can hopefully use the array in my javascript like so

`<%= content_tag(:div, id: 'mycontainer', data: {source: @tweets_array})%>`

In my javascript file, I want to set a variable `var data` to be `@tweets_array` so I can do some simply D3 visualization, so I call the following

`var data = $('#mycontainer').data('source');`

However, the above doesn't seem to work. I know that if i simply set  `var data = [1,2,3,4,5]` then it works.

What is wrong with my way of retrieving the array from the view and passing it into the javascript?

This method is taken from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427947/how-to-get-rails-controller-variable-in-js-file)

Comment: What is the html output that gets rendered by the call to `content_tag`?

Comment: @csum The output is `{:id=>"mycontainer", :data=>{:source=>[48.95, .......]}}`, which seems right (I have numeric data in the array)

Comment: shouldn't content_tag be printing html?

Comment: Yep. It's trying to interpret the attributes as HTML... See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually dislike having to add a new gem everytime as a solution, but [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) has has been instrumental in all of my d3 work within rails.

You set your variables in your controller as 
`gon.variable_name = variable_value`

And retrieve them in your javascript as `gon.variable_name`

Comment: Not the most ideal, but thanks for introducing Gon. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Your array needs to be written as json in the div:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, id: 'mycontainer', data: {source: @tweets_array.to_json})%>
```

Should produce the html:

```
<div id="mycontainer" data-source="[48.95, .......]"></div>
```

Now javascript can parse the attribute:

```
var data = JSON.parse($("#mycontainer").data('source'));
```

You may also need to use `raw` or `html_safe` when printing the json on the rails side.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why what you have doesn't work is because `content_tag` helper expects the 2nd parameter to be the content of the tag (not attributes).

So,

`<%= content_tag(:div, id: 'mycontainer', data: {source: @tweets_array})%>`

won't work, but

`<%= content_tag(:div, "", id: 'mycontainer', data: {source: @tweets_array})%>`

will! See the difference?

Here is a very simple test to verify. View can be as simple as this:

```
<h1>Listing Tweets</h1>

<% @tweets_array = [1,2,3,4,5] %>
<%= content_tag(:div, "", id: 'mycontainer', data: {source: @tweets_array})%>

<button id="sourceBtn">Show source</button>
```

Then,  in your `application.js` you can have the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(function () {
  $('#sourceBtn').click(function(){
    var data = $('#mycontainer').data('source');
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

As you can see, when you click the button - you see the result